# Как подключить андроид телефон к кали линукс

Tags: android, linux, debian, kali-linux, vmware

У меня возникла проблема подключения телефона на виртуальную машину где стоит кали линукс, виндовс видит телефон, но линукс ни как его не видит. Что делать?

Comment: извиняюсь за свою граматику

Comment: 1. пакет adb установлен? 2. подключиет смартфон и приложите вывод `$ adb devices` к тексту вопроса, нажав [edit]

Comment: думаю, для начала нужно уточнить, что такое "видит".  Для некоторых "видит" - это при подключении запускается какая то программа, которая дает полный доступ к внутренностям телефона.

Comment: Вы не указали какую виртуальную машину используете. Не каждая умеет подключать usb-порты напрямую, к тому же эту опцию наверное нужно включить. Также в таргет-системе должен быть установлен adb-драйвер для телефона. Вроде есть вариант переброса соединения с одного adb-демона в другой, но я с таким не сталкивался.

Comment: @KoVadim Использую виртуальную машину vmware, я хочу получить доступ к файлам телефона

Comment: подождем кого то, кто использует vmware.

Comment: @KoVadim ты используешь virtualbox?

Comment: я использую Генту:)

Comment: я про виртуальную машину

Comment: у меня уже линукс, мне не нужны танцы с виртуальной машиной

Comment: ааа, понятно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На виртуалке сеть за натом. Перенастрой мостом.

Comment: Так отладка по tcp-ip не работает из коробки - сначала нужно подключить аппарат по usb и переключить в режим tcp-ip

Comment: @woesss мы ещё не разобрались что значит "видит".

Comment: @eri "видит" значит получить доступ к файлам телефона

Comment: получить доступ к файлам можно несколькими способами

Comment: и как это можно сделать?

Comment: мне нравится через kde-connect/gsconnect

Comment: Все, теперь я смог подключить телефон к линукс. Спасибо тебе.